# Open java project in IntelliJ from git bash

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to open a project in IntelliJ through command line (git bash) like i would do with Visual Studio Code using the command:

```
code .
```

I have create an environment variable in path pointing to the "bin" directory for my IntelliJ installation like this:
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.4\bin
When I run the command:

```
idea .
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know what's wrong? (i do have a JAVA_HOME variable)

Answer (score 1):

I installed Java JDK 32bit in stead of 64bit, and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got intelliJ to start from my git bash terminal:

`idea64.exe .`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).